# Corrupted Line in Daphne and Apollo

Tags: ovidius, metamorphoses

Why is Line 546 of Ovid's *Daphne and Apollo* considered a "corrupted line"?
Here's the section in which it is contained:

> 543 viribus absumptis expalluit illa citaeque
>   544 victa labore fugae spectans Peneidas undas
>   545 'fer, pater,' inquit 'opem! si flumina numen habetis,
>   546 [quae facit ut laedar mutando perde figuram.]
>   547 qua nimium placui, mutando perde figuram!'
>   548 vix prece finita torpor gravis occupat artus,
>   549 mollia cinguntur tenui praecordia libro,
>   550 in frondem crines, in ramos bracchia crescunt,
>   551 pes modo tam velox pigris radicibus haeret,
>   552 ora cacumen habet: remanet nitor unus in illa.

Comment: For clarification: this is in [Book 1 of Ovid's *Metamorphoses*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/ovid/ovid.met1.shtml)

Answer (score 4):

What you quote are lines as they appear at http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/ovid/ovid.met1.shtml .

My own copy is the 1909 Teubner edition "*cum emendationis summario*", and, for what it's worth, it differs from the lines you have quoted:

(545) 'Fer pater' inquit 'opem! Tellus,' ait, 'hisce, vel istam /  (545 ! ) Quae fecit, ut laedar, mutando perde figuram?' / Vix prece finita, torpor gravis occupat artus, / Mollia cinguntur tenui praecodia libro, / (550) In frondem crines, in ramos bracchia crescunt: / Pes modo tam velox  pigris radicibus . . . . .

[Your] line 547 does not appear. The *emendatio* as given by the [Teubner's] editor is :

"  545, 547 recepi quae in proecdosi posthabui. non est probabile solum Peneum invocatum voluisse poetam, a patre filiam mutatam fuisse. Tellurum aut crediderim desumptam ex *Aesch. Promethei vv. 565 581 H*., quam fabulam relegisse eum oportet antequam versum abhinc vigesimum conscriberet, aut ex *fabula Antiochena*, quam habet Nonnus Dion. XXXIII 214 (Munro, Aetna p.43). "

Comment: Some good info here: "Harley MS 2610, and OVID, *Met.* I 544-546" ([*The Classical Review*](https://books.google.com/books?id=u-onAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA140&lpg=RA1-PA140) It's a good start to mention that there are other renderings of the line (obviously--the one in the OP's edition is a nonsensical repetition), but some reference to an authoritative critical edition would probably be needed to settle what exactly causes these discrepancies

Comment: @brianpck The Teubner is usually considered an "authoritative critical edition" on a par with, say, the Oxford Classical Texts. Isn't the discrepancy merely the result of different attempts at interpolating a missing portion — as I was taught? It would, naturally, be good to know how much authority is accorded to the interpolating editors (whoever they were).

Comment: Take a look at the first page of the article I cited: it proposes a different text (as well as alternate MSS readings) with what seems like good authority, though it *was* written in 1919 (old, but still newer than Teubner)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only access a few brief lines from the article, which isn't much use. In any event, to look for the "cause of these discrepancies" outwith what I suggested doesn't to me seem likely to give as strong an answer as either of us might wish.

Comment: The latest Teubner edition of Metamorphoses was in 1998, by William Anderson https://www.degruyter.com/viewbooktoc/product/33013 imho nothing can beat Teubner